# Drag and Drop GUI PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

can anyone fix my problem? I have a simple GUI which there are 3 icons on the left side and there is a graphical view widget on the left side of the screen,I want to be able to drop the icon instances after pressing on them wherever I like on the graphic view,but they all automatic position at the center of the widget and when you drop a few of them together it looks like a mess.

[Here is how it looks when running:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3tLg.png)

and here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QToolButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap, QDrag
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt, QMimeData

class DraggableIcon(QToolButton):
    def __init__(self, icon_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setIcon(QIcon(icon_path))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))
        self.setFixedSize(64, 64)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True) 
        self.icon_path = icon_path

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.drag_start(event)

    def drag_start(self, event):
        drag = QDrag(self)
        mime_data = QMimeData()
        mime_data.setText(self.icon_path)
        drag.setMimeData(mime_data)

        pixmap = QPixmap(self.icon_path)
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())

        drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction)

class MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, scene):
        super().__init__(scene)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        mime_data = event.mimeData()
        if mime_data.hasText():
            icon_path = mime_data.text()
            pixmap = QPixmap(icon_path)
            icon_item = self.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)
            scene_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())  # Convert drop position to scene coordinates
            icon_item.setPos(scene_pos)
            event.acceptProposedAction()

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Drag and drop")

        central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(central_widget)

        icon_layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Here we create Draggable Icon instances
        self.icons = ["athena_icon.png", "poseidon_icon.png", "ares_icon.png"]
        for icon_path in self.icons:
            icon_button = DraggableIcon(icon_path)
            icon_layout.addWidget(icon_button)

        graphics_view = MyGraphicsView(QGraphicsScene(self))
        main_layout.addLayout(icon_layout)
        main_layout.addWidget(graphics_view)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.resize(800, 800)  # We set the initial size
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

.

Comment: First get the position, *then* add the item. Also, consider setting the scene alignment to top left *and* setting the scene rect.